# Not able to retrive json values in full calender using struts2

Tags: json, struts2

In my jsp page
iterated buttons //let me take  i got two buttons on iteration

```
<s:iterator value="%{#session.allrefrence}">    

<button class="btn " style=" background: #DB7093;color: white; " id="ref" value="%{refrenceid}" ></button>                                  
</s:iterator>
```

//after clicking a button i ll send its refference id to controller

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#ref')
            .click(
                    function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'title',
                    right: ' today prev,next'
                }, 
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                editable: false,
                dataType: 'json', 
                 events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
             $.ajax({
                 url: '/Management/Calenderpick',
                 data : {reffrenceid : $('#ref').val()},                                 
           });


success: function(data) {
                        var events = [];
                        events.push({
                            title: data.title,
                            start: data.start,
                            end:   data.end
                        });
                    callback(events);
                    },
                    error: function(e, x, y) {
                      console.log(e);
                      console.log(x);
                      console.log(y);
                    }
       }

          });
        });  

     }); 


    </script>



This is my xml configuration



    <action name="Studentleave"
                class="com.sms.controller.calender.leave">
                <result type="json">
                    <param name="root">calenderList</param>
                </result>
            </action>
```

I My action class

```
private String title;
    private String start;
    private String end;

    public String execute() {

         title = "EventXYZ";
         start = "2016-12-02";
         end = "2016-12-03";



        return SUCCESS;
    }
//getters and setters
```

Whats wrong with this code I am not able to print titles value in my calender and any help will be appreciable

Comment: I never tried serializing multiple root objects, if it is possible try them getting as `data.title`, `data.start` likewise ...also could you show full `Action class` ?

Comment: there is nothing in my action class other than getter and setters and please tell how can i get values as data.title and i am new to stutrs2

Comment: show your call to action `Calenderpick`  ajax ...

Comment: ok...fullcalender has attribute `events:` to action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this  + remove all `<param name="root"></param>` from your action result

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'title',
                right: ' today prev,next'
            }, 
            defaultDate: '2016-09-06', 
            editable: false,
            dataType: 'json', 
            events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Management/Calenderpick',
                    data: {
                        // data if you are passing
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        var events = [];
                        events.push({
                            title: data.title,
                            start: data.start,
                            end:   data.end
                        });
                    callback(events);
                    },
                    error: function(e, x, y) {
                      console.log(e);
                      console.log(x);
                      console.log(y);
                    }
              });
          }
      });
    });
```

Comment: did you removed `<param name="root"></param>`

Comment: and your `action's execute` gets execured ?

Comment: yea it has executed

Comment: it may be because i set `defaultDate: '2016-09-06',`, and you were checking same month

Comment: hi i am trying to send data to controller but i am getting error

Comment: why you have removed success method ?

Comment: I think you are passing **List** i.e.`calenderList` , so **iterate it** or access it using `data[0].title` , `data[0].start`, and `data[0].end`